# How can I set a data set parameter using two/combined parameters 1 date and 1 time with condition

Tags: sql, eclipse, amazon-redshift, birt

This is my current query :

```
where cast(dateadd(h,cast(substring(case when timezoneoffset = 'Z' then '0' else timezoneoffset end,1,3) as int),cast(transactionendtime::timestamp as timestamp without time zone)) as date) >= ?
and cast(dateadd(h,cast(substring(case when timezoneoffset = 'Z' then '0' else timezoneoffset end,1,3) as int),cast(transactionendtime::timestamp as timestamp without time zone)) as date) <= ?
```

here are the parameters from my data set:
[image]

**rp_startdate** and **rp_enddate** data type is *Date*, **required parameters**

 while **rp_startTime** and **rp_endTime** is *Time* value is 24 hour with hourly interval, also these are **not required parameters**
[image]
[image]

Now what I want is when the user didn't select *starttime* **or** *endtime* (Null Value) then my query stays like that only read the **start and end date**, But when the user selects *starttime* **and** *endtime*, then I want to query it to have a condition combine the **startDate and endTime** & **endDate and endTime** as **DateTime**, then on my query pass that use that two for the query

Additional info for queries:
**Start and End Time** = Null Value | **Use Current Query**
**Same Date**, **StartTime** = Null Value | **Use Current Query**
**Same Date**, **EndTime** = Null Value | **Use Current Query**
**Same Date**, **Start and End Time** = Not Null | **Change Query to include time**
**Different Date**, **Start and End Time** = Any Value | **Use Current Query**

Comment: So the only parameter available in the query is transactionendtime? What value do it show when the user does and doesn't select a value for the time?

Comment: @JimJimson , the parameters in the query are read by index so the startDate parameter is the first '?', the transactionendtime is from the data source, please see this link: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc%2Fbirt%2Frp-HowToDefineADataSetParameter.html

Comment: Ahh I see, I got it backwards. I'll have a look in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle this by converting both of the inputs to timestamps, but using NVL() to handle when the user doesn't enter the time:

Psuedocode:

```
WHERE cast(dateadd(h,cast(substring(case when timezoneoffset = 'Z' then '0' else timezoneoffset end,1,3) as int),cast(transactionendtime::timestamp as timestamp without time zone)) as date) BETWEEN (date(?) || ' ' || NVL(?, '00:00:00'))::TIMESTAMP AND (date(?) || ' ' || NVL(?, '23:59:59'))::TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: we cant use named parameter in birt, may I know how can I apply this to my current query for the "transactionendtime"

Comment: Ok, try that. This assumes that the start time and end time parameters still come through even when they're not entered by the user.

Comment: thank u it worked, just made a a small changes to as date to as datetime, also can you please tell how can I do this to disregard both starttime and endtime if one of them is null, please see *Additional info for queries*

Comment: also is it possible to read the default value of start and end time if starttime  > endtime ?

Comment: You'll need to handle that with a CASE statement. And it will get messy and difficult if you can't reuse the parameters. Like if you have 6 ? placeholders can you tell it which parameter to reuse?